# Difference between OS volume and Music volume levels

Tags: macos, itunes, audio, music, sound-volume

I connected my Macbook Pro to external speakers via the jack port.

I noticed that the macOS volume level and the Music volume level adjustments sounds very different :

- When I set Music's volume level at 100% and adjust the macOS' volume level, it sounds slightly bad, like compressed.
- When I set macOS' volume at 100% and adjust the Music's volume level, it sounds very great with clearer bass and treble.

(By the way, my external speakers' volume is always the same. I notice the sound difference just by playing with masOS' and Music's volume sliders.)

(I also noticed differences when using Senheiser Headphones. These are not the same sound differences than when using speakers but having 100% macOS level and 10% Music volume definitely sounds better)

Do you know where does this sound differences come from ?
Thanks !

System information :

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
- macOS 12.3

Comment: Is this at the same relative output level, or are you compensating in the external amp? Theoretically, digital summing shouldn't care where in the chain the levels are applied, so long as there are no overs [greater than 0dBFS], but there may be some slight difference if you're pushing the input to an analog stage vs later in the chain. [which, I suppose is techno-babble for yes, it kind of makes sense in some cases, especially to something 'cheap' like a h'phone out' You may also have an impedance mismatch if you're running to an amp rather than h'phones, which could emphasise the effect.

Comment: No changes to the level of external speakers. Only adjusting masOS' and Music's volume sliders. (I edited)

Comment: I can only assume the difference is on the input to the op-amp for the output socket. Music at 100% is too high for it. I don't know how the circuit works, exactly where the DA conversion happens, or even how much headroom is allowed for in the digital circuitry, so I can't answer this with any certainty. It does make sense, for a given value of 'sense'. I just cannot categorically say exactly how in this instance. Pro audio works in 64-bit floating point math to do this type of operation with zero distortion. A laptop headphone out is not going to be doing that at all.